Change line spacing in a ToC
I would like to customize the spacing in a titletoc-generated mini-ToC, by reducing the baseline within a given subsection title when it has to be spread over several lines, and/or slightly increasing the separation between different section or subsection titles. My aim is to make my mini-ToC look more balanced and easier to read.
Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\startcontents[parts]

\section{First section, with a rather long name}
\subsection{Now a subsection with quite a long name as well}
\subsection{A shorter subsection title}
\section{Second section, with a rather long name too}
\stopcontents[parts]

\begin{minipage}[t]{6cm}
\printcontents[parts]{}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

Here are my issues with the mini-ToC produced (they don't show up quite clearly here but my custom setting makes them blatant; here I just want to make clear which spaces I'd like to tweak):

Thanks in advance!

Note: changing the value of \baselinestretch acts on the baseline of section titles but not on subsection ones. Being able to do the latter would already help me greatly.

I found all the details I wanted in the following thread: How to change spaces between items in Table of Contents.
In my case, using the \spacing{.95} to reduce the global spacing of the ToC and adding a small space between subsections using \pretocmd{\subsection}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{2\p@}}}{}{} did the trick.
